# Input parâmetros AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, json

Estou começando a aprender AJAX e estou com um dúvida simples . Quero passar o valor de um input porém estou tendo erro ao realizar o teste . O Código é bem simples por isto vou colar ele completo. Quando passo o valor fixo o alerta funciona . Quando tento passar o valor pelo input aparece o seguinte erro :

> Undefined Index .

Já olhei em alguns fóruns , vidéos e etc mas até agora não consegui .

Em resumo , quero pegar o valor do input pelo ID porém da erro Undefined Index .

```
<script>
$.ajax({ method: "POST", url: "php.php", 
data: { 
    nome: $('#nome').val(), 
    senha:"John" } }) 
.done(function( msg ) { alert( "Data Saved: " + msg ); });

</script>
</head>


<form id="form">

    <label>nome:</label>
    <input name="nome" id="nome"> </input>

    <label>senha:</label>
    <input name="senha" id="senha"> </input>

    <button type="submit"> Enviar </button>

</form>
```

Pagina PHP:

```
$nome =$_POST['nome'];
echo $nome;
echo " recebido";
```

Comment: Não está muito claro qual o problema. Passar o valor do msg? para qual input?

Comment: A consulta `AJAX` é feita quando? Na inicialização da página ou no envio do formulário?

Comment: A consulta é realizada no envio do formulário . A intenção é que o valor digitado seja recebido no alerta

Comment: Não falta colocar no formulário o `method="post"`?

Comment: Acredito que se colocar o method e o action não irei utilizar o Ajax . A ideia seria trabalhar de forma assíncrona coletando a variável via php e expressando o valor digitado via ajax

Answer (score -1):

O que acontece é que você não determinou um evento para o disparo do Ajax.
Como você declarou a tag script antes do seu form html a função foi executada antes do formulário ter sido carregado.

Se você declarar a tag script embaixo do form verá que ele enviará a requisição e não retornará mais o erro de undefined, porém você ainda não receberá o dado desejado.

**Para que isso aconteça, você deve determinar um evento para o disparo do Ajax após ter preenchido os campos.**

Também é interessante você adicionar este evento dentro do **$(document).ready()** para você ter certeza que o documento foi carregado por completo antes de executar as funções.

Exemplo:
Neste caso atribuí um evento click ao elemento button apenas para demonstrar, porém você pode colocar o tipo de evento que melhor se encaixa para o seu código.

```
<form id="form">
    <label>nome:</label>
    <input name="nome" id="nome"> </input>

    <label>senha:</label>
    <input name="senha" id="senha"> </input>

    <button type="submit"> Enviar </button>
</form>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button).click(function(){
        $.ajax({ 
            method: "POST", 
            url: "php.php", 
            data: { 
                nome: $('#nome').val(), 
                senha:"$('#senha').val()" } }) 
         .done(function( msg ) { 
             alert( "Data Saved: " + msg ); 
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Funcionou ! Muito Obrigado :)